# How to redirect everything after slash to domain before?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

This is what I'm trying to do:

I want `example.com/car/{whatever}` redirected to `example.com/{whatever}`.

For example, `example.com/car/honda` should be redirected to `example.com/honda`

BUT if there is nothing after `/car/`, then just leave it as that.

How can i do that in .htaccess ?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing a prefix from a URL is pretty simple, just

```
RewriteRule ^car/(.*)$ /$1 [R,L]
```

In order to keep a special case, you must put it in front

```
RewriteRule ^car/$ - [L]
```

This rule says, if there is just `car/` leave it alone, see [RewriteRule substitution](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rhs)

> **- (dash)**
> A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag (see below) needs to be applied without changing the path.