# Remove home from website url

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

How can i remove /home from my website url so that my site can only be accessed by mywebsite.com and mywebsite.com/home redirected to mywebsite.com

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#301 redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]


</IfModule>
```

Comment: I answered a similar question recently, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40431327/1741542

Comment: I would expect that will collide with other things served by that domain. And if not - then may ask why you want to rewrite that instead of simply changing the base url?

Comment: @arkascha I already changed the base url..home is my default controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect everything after slash to domain before?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430698/how-to-redirect-everything-after-slash-to-domain-before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this right below `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/home
RewriteRule ^(.*)home$ http://yourwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```